# JQuery How-strong-is-your-password bar

Tags: jquery, passwords, measure, meter

Is there a jQuery project out there, that create on of these "Password-strength-meters" right by a password box and updates the strength-bar when something is typed into the field?

Do you know any good ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a comprehensive list:

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/10-password-strength-meter-scripts-for-a-better-registration-interface/

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if exists an jQuery plugin for that, but you can use this google url: [https://www.google.com/accounts/RatePassword?Passwd={0}](https://www.google.com/accounts/RatePassword?Passwd=%7B0%7D)

EDIT: [here an example using jQuery](http://gofrom.us/27QP).

Comment: woot for sending passwords over unencrypted GET!